# Enterprise Configuration of Workspace mechanic

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I am using Google's Workspace Mechanic to configure my eclipse environment. All seems to work fine, except that for any fresh installation, the workspace mechanic opens up with a default location of its own `(~/.eclipse/mechanic)` to look for preference files.

As given in their documentation i tried including their code

> (/instance/com.google.eclipse.mechanic/mechanicSourceDirectories=/shared/eclipse/tasks\:${user_homedir}/.eclipse/mechanic)

in my `plugin_customization.ini` , but it does not work for me.

Does anyone have any other idea as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows, I found that when using the recent Eclipse Juno and the latest Workspace Mechanic I had to do the following:

Edit the (Java EE):

```
...\Eclipse_Juno_SR1\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.jee_1.5.1.20120828-0743\plugin_customization.ini
```

and add the following line at the end:

```
com.google.eclipse.mechanic/mechanicSourceDirectories=c:\\...\\eclipse_extensions\\WorkspaceMechanics
```

in order for the plugin to recognize the above directory as the shared folder...
The plugin preferences now correctly references the folder !

Answer (score 2):

Quite late, but I just needed the same configuration.

First locate your plugin_customization.ini (eg. 'find -name plugin_customization.ini' in your eclipse folder).
I had two files with same name, located in **org.eclipse.platform** and **org.eclipse.epp.package.jee**.

For me, the jee one was relevant and you can configure it as JSON Array.

```
com.google.eclipse.mechanic/mechanicSourceDirectories=["http\://server/mechanics/tasks.json","/tmp"]
```

This example shows how to configure a folder (/tmp) and via http location.

Comment: This does not work for me,
Workspace Mechanics now has one entry `"http\://server/mechanics/tasks.json","/tmp"`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is for Eclipse on Linux/Unix. If you are running Eclipse on Windows you will need a different path.

Another aproch is to put the preferencces in another file and point to that file from your `eclipse.ini` with a line such as

`-Declipse.pluginCustomization=/var/wsm/current/my.properties`

or eclipse startup with

```
eclipse -pluginCustomization /var/wsm/current/my.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (for **Eclipse Luna in Windows**).

1. **Open** the `Luna/plugins` folder
2. **Search** for a folder that begins with `org.eclipse.epp.package`.
   (and I ended up with `org.eclipse.epp.package.java_4.4.1.20140925-1820`)
3. **Go** inside that folder and edit `plugin_customization.ini`
4. **Append** the following at the end (to point to `\\sharedserver\share\DEV\Workspace-Prefs-Luna`):

`#Workspace Mechanic Settings
com.google.eclipse.mechanic/mechanicSourceDirectories=\\\\\sharedserver\\share\\DEV\\Workspace-Prefs-Luna`

5. **Save** and **Close** the file
6. **Restart** Eclipse