# Best Practice to distribute a Eclipse setup for a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, development-environment

I'm looking for some best practices to rollout/setup a complete project setup with Eclipse to my dev team.

It's a maven based project that will work without Eclipse. But we want to distribute a preconfigure Eclipse version that have all plugins installed, we want to have a local update site to rollout update of this setup and so on.

Is there any good way to achieve this kind of setup? I know that i can provide a update site which contain some plugins, but can i define a set of plugins?

Is it possible that Eclipse pmd, Checkstyle, Findbugs and the code formatter use the settings from Maven?

Here are the two most important questions for me:

1. How to define a plugin set for an Eclipse installation, so that all developers have the same set of plugins installed.
2. Any way to use the configurations from pmd, Findbugs, Checkstyle and code formatter from Maven to be used inside eclipse

Comment: Multiple questions combined here. Ask separate specific questions or edit the post and explain the pre-context and add all the question at the bottom clearly.

Comment: You might split up your question into two topics. So far both answers are about the configuration part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside of your Eclipse installation via update site, here a possible plugin to manage configurations (question 2):

To distribute any settings of 'window-preference' to your whole dev team I can recomment 'workspace mechanics'.

You can record your settings and then provide them via your dev server.

If you distribute a shared Eclipse it's also easy to provide the proper workspace mechanics URL for any Eclipse installation (see [Enterprise Configuration of Workspace mechanic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008319/enterprise-configuration-of-workspace-mechanic/10995660#10995660)).

Changes to the settings are checked on startup and the developers are always up to date.

Further information can be found on the official project page: https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/

Comment: which last answered questions for an howto? (put it in your post)

Comment: Hi, can you put the link in your answer. I cannot find the right answer from you. Any official documentation ?

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer now (was to lazy to search it on the phone yesterday)

Comment: Cool. This looks like the solution im looking for. I do not want to rely on the disciplin of the developers.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues some time ago. Setting up eclipse with a bunch of plugins is really annoying. proko mentioned a plugin I didn't know, so I compared it to the solution I am using right now.
After 15 minutes of installing, trying it out and reading the doc, I gave up because it seems too heavyweighted for my needs.

The solution I am using myself is yatta Profiles: http://profiles.yatta.de

Especially your first requirement can be tackled with it. You can install all the plugins your team needs, click on a button to upload the configuration, and send the link to your team. Your colleagues just have to download your profile. All plugins will be installed automatically.

Here’s a link to an Eclipse profile with the plugins you mentioned (pmd, checkstyle, findbugs, maven): https://marketplace.yatta.de/profiles/a7Ig

Answer (score 1):

This is part of a Development-Handbook in your Team!

All important plugins contains support for external configuration, also checkstyle, code-formatter and findbugs.

Distribute those configurations in a single website.

code-formatter: Open `window`->`preferernces` `Java`>`Code-style`>`formatter` -> `Import` and specify the configuration from a website you created (its a file dialog but you can specify uri's also).

Checkstyle: Open `window`->`preferernces`>`Checkstyle` and press `New ...` then choose `External Configuration File`

Findbugs: similar to Checkstyle.

There is no other way. We use a wiki to distribute the Development-Handbook and the Configuration.

Comment: Often there are maven plugins who check against checkstyle-configuration and findbugs-configuration. Is there a Eclipse-Formatter-Plugin in Maven? I do not know.

Comment: I've used Jalopy in the past, but i switched to IntelliJ for years now. I need to check if the eclipse formatter and checkstyle are easy to sychnronize.

Comment: We will use a Wiki as well. But i want to preconfigure everything as far as possible. The dev team should care about this part of the project.

Comment: If those settings are configured via Window Preferences, they can be configured and imported automatically, see my answer. Otherwise you rely on the developers to be uptodate manually, which is obviously not the best choice.

Comment: Hi, some progress on my site. I'm using the distrobuilder from https://github.com/tomsontom/distrobuilder and adding some functionality myself. With this i can build a custom distro and integrate with workspace mechanic the external configs. Works for local and enterprise setups.